# Azure storage - disable use of authorization header

Tags: azure, authorization

Is it possible to configure Azure storage to ignore the contents of the authorization HTTP header? 
It seems that Azure always tries to make use of the header value even when configured for anonymous access and receiving pure GET requests.
Leaving the field blank is not an option in my scenario.

1. Configure Azure for anonymous access.
2. Use a plugin like Postman to create a GET request.
3. Set the "Authorization" header to a value like "this is a non-azure related authorization header which for technical reasons is part of the request".
4. Azure responds with HTTP status code 400.

Request WITHOUT authorization header:
[image: Request WITHOUT authorization header]

Request WITH authorization header:
[image: Request WITH authorization header]

Comment: Would you mind explaining? I downloaded a public blob (i.e. GET with anonymous request) and didn't see the authorization header. See the fiddler trace here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGIXl.png.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I edited my question to include reproduction steps.

Comment: I see. Can you share a concrete example? Like for example the type of REST operation you're trying to do. AFAIK, only Get Blob and List Blobs operation can work anonymously. All other operations would require authorization header and you can't omit that.

Comment: I've added two screenshots showing the issue. As mentioned initially I'd like to know if Azure can be configured to ignore the Authorization header on e.g. all GET requests.

Comment: For 1st one, please check the container ACL. For anonymous access, the container's ACL should be either `Blob` or `Container`. My guess is that the container's ACL is private thus authorization header becomes required and server calculates the authorization header on its own and compares it with the one sent in request. Since you sent a dummy authorization header (which is not base64 encoded) you get 400 error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I wouldn't be able to get a 404 response from a private container when not providing _any_ kind of authorization as this would potentially allow me to probe for valid and invalid resources without valid credentials - but I'll try to check the configuration, thanks.

Comment: Yes you will. I'm pretty sure of that. Please try on your end.

Comment: I just verified that the container is configured as Public, so no luck on that end.

Comment: Maybe the short answer simply is "No, it's not possible." :|