# Can I disable Authorization Header for publicly available Azure Blobs?

Tags: azure, http-headers, authorization, azure-blob-storage

This may be a duplicate of [Azure storage - disable use of authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340755/azure-storage-disable-use-of-authorization-header). But that one is 6 years old and never got an answer. Also there were some misunderstandings in that thread, that I will try to avoid.

Reproduce by:

1. Create an Azure Blob Container with Anonymous access (Container or Blob Access Level)
2. Call a resource without headers results in => 200 (this is what we want)
3. Call the same resource WITH (for example) a header "Authorization: bearer blabla" reults in 
   => 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

In my scenario it requires a large effort to have the clients rewrite their logic so as NOT to pass the authorization header (which is required for essentially all other requests). It is unfortunate that, even though the Authorization header is NOT required in order to retrieve data, providing one such header denies my clients access to the blob storage.

EDIT: Further explanation: The clients are mobile apps that and I want to be backwards compatible as I change the storage location of my files to Azure.

Comment: If the blob is publicly available why do you want to do #3 above?

Comment: This is simply the use case I have. I am not in control of the clients that will use this data, and they pass this header in all requests. It seems like a mistake on Microsoft part to fail request when an optional header is applied...

Comment: DId you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, we ended up having the clients use a different header name for our auth header :/