# Public blob url not accessible when Authorization header is sent

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Storage account, with **Allow Blob public access enabled** and a container  with public access level set to **Blob**.
I have uploaded a dummy image to the container and I am able to access it in any browser. If I set a dummy authorization request header to the blob url, then the image can not be accessed anymore.
Is there a way to ignore the authorization header if public access is enabled?

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting the dummy authorization request, when you can do a simple GET request?

Comment: The only way i see you can do that is by having an adaptor Azure function to handle your GET request and strip the Authorisation header when accessing the storage file and return the response to the caller.

Comment: A similar question was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340755/azure-storage-disable-use-of-authorization-header

Comment: The blob url will be used by the third party application that adds the authorization header by default and I trying to find a way to tell azure to ignore it, if public access was granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the Storage Account there isn't any such option. You could however try one of the following:

Setup an Azure CDN for your Storage Account and add a rule engine for the CDN endpoint to remove the `Authorization` header of the request.

Create an endpoint (e.g. Function App) that merely redirects to the specified blob. In the usual case the client will follow the redirect but strip the authorization header from request.